# Highlighting the differences in matched rows between two tables

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm building a report that will tell me whether the data from two tables is matching in specific columns. So far, I'm able to find which rows do not have a match in the opposite table, but now I'm wondering - is there a way to highlight which column is not matching? i.e. show what data is unmatched, whether it's quantity, commission, etc. Assumption is trade date, broker, and ticker must be matching.

Keeping in mind the tables do not have the same structure, but do have some column names in common.

I'm matching the tables based on the following:

t = table1 and tt = table2

```
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   @table2 tt 
                   WHERE  t.broker = tt.broker 
                          AND ( t.ticker = tt.ticker 
                                 OR t.isin = tt.isin 
                                 OR t.sedol = tt.sedol 
                                 OR t.cusip = tt.cusip ) 
                          AND t.[trade date] = tt.[trade date] 
                          AND t.quantity = tt.quantity 
                          AND ABS(t.[gross commission]) = ABS(tt.[gross commission])
                  ) 
       AND t.[gross commission] <> 0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: *highlight* how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to use a column to tell you where to look for discrepancies, one option is to join the two tables and create a column that basically concatenates the column names when their values in the respective tables don't match. Something along these lines..

```
concat_ws(',',
case when t.broker<> tt.broker then 'broker' end,
case when t.ticker <> tt.ticker then 'ticker' end,
case when t.isin <> tt.isin then 'isin'  end,
case when t.sedol <> tt.sedol then 'sedol' end,
case when t.cusip <> tt.cusip ) then 'cusip' end,
case when t.[trade date]<> tt.[trade date] then 'trade date' end,
case when t.quantity <> tt.quantity then 'quantity' end,
case when ABS(t.[gross commission]) <> ABS(tt.[gross commission]) then 'gross commission' end) as unmatched_columns
```